# Smallest and Largest element in an open Interval

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I have an interval $I=(0,1)$ I want to prove that there is no smallest and largest interval in I.
For smallest I have below statement.
$$ \forall \, x \in I, \exists \, y \in I \, such \,that \, y<x $$
or
$$ \forall \, x \in I , \exists   \epsilon >0, such \,that \, (x-\epsilon )\in I $$

For largest I have below statment
$$ \forall \, x \in I, \exists \, y \in I \, such \,that \, y >x $$
or
$$ \forall \, x \in I , \exists   \epsilon >0, such \,that \, (x+\epsilon )\in I $$

Do these statements reflect for nonexistent of the smallest and largest elements in Interval I.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first and third statement are exactly saying what you want. The second and forth are equivalent in the case of real intervals, but you would technically have the prove that before using it.